# unable to get the row count and access the table data in a table using webdriver 2.0 (Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
 <div id="OmContentSection" class="modified_content ui-content"          role="main" data-role="content" style="padding: 0px;">     
     <div>
     <div id="positionsContainer" class="WL_watchlist_listitem">
     <table id="tblMainData" class="WL_watchlist_table" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody id="positionsList">
         <tr id="A">
           <td id="A_daysToExpiry" class="fieldRendererText "/>
           <td id="A_targetProfit" class="fieldRendererText "/>
           <td id="A_stopLossPrice" class="fieldRendererText "/>
           <td id="A_note" class="fieldRendererText "/>
           <td id="A markChange" class="fieldRendererText ">-2.13</td>
           <td id="A_markPercChange" class="fieldRendererText ">-5.18%      </td></tr>
        <tr id="AA">
        <tr id="AL">
        <tr id="AR">
        <tr id="AT">
        <tr id="AM">
        <tr id="AT">
        <tr id="BAC">
        <tr id="M">
       </tbody>
      </table>
 </div>
```

`

Below is my code to handle the table data:

```
   WebElement table = driver.findElement(OH_positions);


    WebElement tablebody = driver.findElement(By.id("positionsList"));

        // Now get all the TR elements from the table
        List<WebElement> allRows = tablebody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        System.out.println("row size :"+allRows.size());

        // And iterate over them, getting the cells
        for (WebElement row : allRows) {
            List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int columncount = cells.size();
            System.out.println("Column size :"+columncount);
            System.out.println("data:"+cells.get(row);


        }
```

in my code i have tried several ways to identify the table and the rows 
However i am getting row size as 0 in each instance.Each time I am getting the same response as '0'I don't know how to get this solved.

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the closing `</tbody>` and several closing `</tr>`s - copy&paste error?

Comment: yes Basti.. you are right there was a typo mistake.

Comment: changes made as per the comments mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess row count is not right. You are trying to use `cells.get()` and not providing the index instead passing `WebElement`. Try something as follows

```
// And iterate over them, getting the cells
for (WebElement row : allRows) {
    List cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    int columncount = cells.size();
    System.out.println("Column size :" + columncount);
    int cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")).size();
    System.out.println("Column size :"+cols);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs Saifur.